# Concatenation of string and Substring using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am currently trying to concatenate a string with a sub string of 'First_name'.

Here is my current code

```
-<USERNAME xtt:severity="error" xtt:required="true" xtt:fixedLength="10">
<xsl:value-of select=concat"('ad', 
substring(.,ws:Personal/ws:Name_Data/ws:First_Name 1,1)))"/>
</USERNAME>
```

The xslt is coming back with an error and not transforming the xml document.

Comment: Start by comparing the number of opening vs. closing parentheses. Then look at what the arguments of the `substring()` function are supposed to be. --- Also please read: [mcve].

Comment: Don't tell us that something is coming back with an error without telling us what the error message is. You might not find it useful, but we almost certainly will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your input, the current context and the expected result, we can only guess. I am guessing you want to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select=concat"('ad', substring(ws:Personal/ws:Name_Data/ws:First_Name, 1, 1))"/>
```

---

This will append the first letter of `ws:First_Name` to the string `"ad"`.